# How to debug ClassNotFoundException on client environment

Tags: java, debugging, classpath

One of our customers is facing an issue:
Sometimes when he runs our java application it throws `ClassNotFoundException`. The jar containing the "missing" class is correctly placed under the class path, and the issue on his environment is inconsistent (depending on the way we invoke the application - command line or shortcut, and on other environment factors).

We would like to hand him a debug version that prints the paths and URLs where the missing class is being looked for, so that we can understand why it is not found, and get the problem resolved.

We tried `-verbose:class`, but it only prints the successfully loaded classes and their actual path. Is there a way to print the paths where each (or better only missing) class is being searched for?

Comment: Check the system environment variables it might be adding the same class twice.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb - can you explain how can a class be loaded twice?

Comment: It probably wont cause a classnotfoundexception.  Can you post more details about the environment variables and how the classpath is set, please.

Comment: Classpath is embedded into an exe generated by install4j. I suspect the issue is with some misconfigured drive mapping on their environment that gets resolved incorrectly depending on how the application is launched.

Answer (score 1):

According to the exception, there's no doubt that there's something wrong about the classpath which causes JVM not finding the class desired.

Now that, you said the missing class is located at the jar, but cannot be found. please try these solutions below.

Try to access other classes, which are placed at either the same specific package as the missing class or any package from this jar. If all succeeds, indicate probably that the the package name is wrong by mistake in the source file against the missing class.

Also, if you are good at using -classpath option, you can debug this issue using javac command in the console.